# Trying to append to an empty list

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to append to the empty `grid_list` which is supposed to hold 9 or 15 words depending on difficulty (irrelevant to question):

```
def list_function(): #creates the list that will be used for the grid from file_content_list
    file_content_list = import_function()
    grid_list = [[,,],[,,],[,,]] #this is the list used to make the grid
    counter = 0 #defines counter which allows iteration
    place = 0 #defines place which is what affects the place in grid_list that the word is added to
    if counter < len(file_content_list): #counter decides how many times the next part loops
        for word in file_content_list:
            grid_list[0][place].append(word) #appends the current word to grid_list at the place of value of place
            place += 1 #adds 1 to place
            counter += 1 #adds 1 to counter
            file_content_list.remove(word) #removes the used word
            print grid_list
    elif counter >= 3 and counter < 6: #if counter is equal to 4, 5 or 6
        for word in file_content_list:
            grid_list[0][place].append(word) #appends the current word to grid_list at the place of value of place
            place += 1
            counter += 1
            file_content_list.remove(word)
            print grid_list
    else:
        for word in file_content_list:
            grid_list[0][place].append(word) #appends the current word to grid_list at the place of value of place
            place += 1
            counter += 1
            file_content_list.remove(word)
            print grid_list
    return grid_list
```

This comes up with the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: 'grid_list[0][place]' is a string, should that be grid_list[0] or grid_list instead

Comment: Look again at the error message: `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. That means that `grid_list[0][place]` is a `str` type

Comment: `grid_list = [[,,],[,,],[,,]]` should cause a `SyntaxError` before this `AttributeError` would even have a chance to come up.

Comment: @pzp raises an excellent point -- your function has a fatal syntax error. Also, note that `elif counter >= 3 and counter < 6: #if counter is equal to 4, 5 or 6` contains a mismatch between code and comment -- your code says 3,4 or 5 but your comment says 4,5 or 6. Such inconsistences suggest that a bug might be lurking. Also -- note that something like `3 <= counter < 6` is possible in Python and is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `grid_list[0][place]` are accessing on element. This element is a string and haven't method to append.

Make `grid_list[0][place] =  word` to put the word in this position.